# Развитие частей речи

Tags: словообразование, деепричастия

Эта часть речи развилась позже других частей на основе одной из них.

Какие формы послужили основой для развития в русском языке части речи, к которой относится выделенное слово: "Смотреть, как гаснут полосы В закатном мраке хвой, ПЬЯНЕЯ звуком голоса, похожего на твой" (Ахматова).

1)инфинитив глагола

2)краткое причастие

3)глагол в прошедшемем времени

4)наречие

5)полное причастие

6)глагол в настоящем времени

Ответ: глагол настоящего времени?

Comment: Проверьте мой вариант. Пожалуйста, а то я сомневаюсь

Comment: Я так понимаю, задачка с какой-то олимпиады? Если да, то посмотрите ещё мой ответ. Людмила наверняка это знает, но она скорее всего смотрит на вопрос с точки зрения ЕГЭ и школьной программы. А тут просматривается некоторая претензия на творческий подход и далеко не школьные знания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вчитаться в вопрос внимательно  (*Какие **формы** послужили основой для развития в русском языке части речи, к которой относится выделенное слово*) , можно заметить, что речь идёт не только о данной словоформе, но вообще о части речи - деепричастии.

**Пьянея**- дееприч. несов вида, образовано от основы **глагола наст. времени**, верно, а деепричастие сов.вида образуется от основы **инфинитива**. Так что здесь ответ - две формы: глагол наст.вр. и инфинитив.

Comment: Спасибо, сама слегка запуталась в этом вопросе. Так как правильный вариант только один. => Правильный ответ глагол настоящего времени, как вы мне и ответили. Тот от которого образовано именно это деепричастие. Огромное спасибо за помощь и за ваш ответ.

Comment: Что ж , это был некорректный вопрос (имеет два верных ответа). Нужно было спросить: какая форма? Но у нас это часто стало встречаться в практике учёбы: с учеников спрашивают строго, а в заданиях ошибки.

Comment: Людмила, Вы имеете в виду современный этап или исторический?

Comment: Вопрос действительно некорректно поставлен. ***Основой*** для развития деепричастий в современном их виде послужили ***причастия***.

Answer (score 1):

> По происхождению деепричастие в русском языке восходит к бесчленной, то есть к краткой, форме именительного падежа причастия и возникло в древнерусском языке вследствие потери форм склонения бесчленных причастий. Однако оно имеет и признаки глагола — например, залог.

[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Понятно, что источник не самый авторитетный, но желающие могут найти аналогичные сведения и в любом авторитетном источнике.

Добавлю, что процесс формирования современного причастия как части речи был весьма длительным и завершился не ранее середины XIX века (а отчасти и сейчас продолжается), так что вопрос о "формах, послуживших основой", сильно зависит от исторического контекста - и вообще от понимания, что такое "форма основы".

*Это не в пику Людмиле, просто вопрос поставлен так, что его можно понимать совершенно по-разному, это и сама Людмила пишет.*

Comment: behemothus, то же самое написано и в корпусной грамматике.

Comment: Серж, да я не сомневался. Это вещи общеизвестные. Искать лень было.